# How to fill combobox in Windows Forms c#

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I try to fill one combobox with MySQL database, but I have a problem. I think everything is OK and I see my old project how to fill the comboboxes. I think all code is the same but I forgot how exactly is filling.

So, this is my code, but combobox is not filled.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Common;
using SR.Service;

namespace SR
{
    public partial class allWorkers : Form
    {
        private WorkerService service;
        MySqlConnection connection;
        string MyConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=SR_database;Uid=root;Pwd='';";


        public allWorkers()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConnectionString);
            service = new WorkerService();
        }

        private void btn_Main6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
            var Main = new Main();
            Main.Show();
        }

        private void btn_createWorker_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConnectionString);
            MySqlCommand cmd;
            connection.Open();

                cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = service.CreateWorker(textBox1.Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Вие създадохте нов работник с име: " + textBox1.Text);


            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(service.GetAllWorkers(), connection);
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
            using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
            {
                da.Fill(dt);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            }
            connection.Close();
        }

        private void allWorkers_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {          

        }

        private void btn_deleteWorker_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            MySqlCommand cmd;
            connection.Open();

            cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = service.selectOnlyWorkerName();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(service.selectOnlyWorkerName(), connection);
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                SuspendLayout();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(reader["worker_name"]);
                }
                ResumeLayout();
            }
            //
            //
            //  MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(service.selectOnlyWorkerName(), connection);
            //  MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
            //
            //  using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
            //  {
            //      da.Fill(dt);
            //      foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            //      {
            //          comboBox1.Items.Add(dr["worker_name"]);
            //      }
            //  }
            //  connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I think I forgot something, but I don't know what I forgot to write. 
Thank you guys.

Comment: that is a creative hybrid between data binding and iterative fill you've invented here :) you have two options: 1) databind by assigning the data table to the comboboxes datasource; 2) loop through dt.Rows and keep your Items.Add approach. Btw. the datatable is empty. Call da.Fill(dt) first. But wait... why is the code to fill the combobox inside its selectedindexchanged handler?!?

Comment: I fotgot where exactly can I paste this code :D seriosly.. Can you give me example how can it work.. and where can I move this code ?

Comment: I try to add da.Fill(dt); but combobox is still empty

Comment: confirm by breakpoint that the code is called. put the call in Form_Load to test.

Comment: relocate the combobox filler code from `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` to `allWorkers_Load`. the first is the event handler that will be called by the framework when a user interacts with the combobox on the form *once it is filled*. it makes no sense to use it to fill itself.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do this,

```
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    cb.Items.Add(dr["yourcol"]);
}
```

Comment: Not working :( I try this but.. combobox is still empty

Comment: @B.Pizhev yes, just debug and see if you are getting right values

Comment: Show the query you have on SQL

Comment: public string selectOnlyWorkerName()
        {
            return "SELECT worker_name FROM workers";
        }

Comment: I not see any values.. My db is not empty.. but maybe I can move this code somewhere but I dont know where :D

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Always when you're about to change something within UI with WinForms consider wrapping this around `SuspendLayout()` and `ResumeLayout()`.

Another thing ... have you ever consider executing your command? Just not to use `SqlDataAdapter` which would make your work easier.

---

*example code:*

```
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(service.selectOnlyWorkerName(), connection);
using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    SuspendLayout();
    while(reader.Read())
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(reader["worker_name"]);
    }
    ResumeLayout();
}
```

*or in case you really need to use `SqlDataAdapter`:*

```
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(service.selectOnlyWorkerName(), connection);
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds,"workers");
SuspendLayout();
foreach ( var row in ds.Tables["workers"].Rows)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add(row[0]);
}
ResumeLayout();
```

---

The code posted above should work perfectly fine and in case it won't then debug if your command actually has some results.

Comment: show us the calling code. prove that it is called using the debugger. if the code is called from within the selectedindexchanged event handler, you have a chicken-egg-problem.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? Does it goes into your handler?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should have handled the DropDown event, rather than SelectedIndexChanged.

DropDown has worked for me in the past.